# gdb itself crashed and quit with 'Segmentation fault (core dumped)' when i ran bt

Tags: c++, linux, gdb

1. I know my `amazing_app` crashed with `SIGSEGV`, this is OK, I can
   fix this with the help of gdb
2. My question is gdb crashed, why is
   that, how to fix it
3. What I did is a). run `gdb amazing_app -c amazing_app.dump`, b). run `bt` to find the call stack
4. Then gdb crashed, it seems there are more backtrace there, but since gdb crashed, there is no chance to display those backtrace

```
root@amazing_host:/coredump# gdb /app/deploy/bin/amazing_app -c cores_readonly/cores/core.20211106135309 
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.10.1
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from /app/deploy/bin/amazing_app...done.
[New LWP 22385]
[New LWP 22388]
[New LWP 22387]
[New LWP 22386]

warning: Could not load shared library symbols for linux-vdso.so.1.
Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?

warning: File "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db-1.0.so" auto-loading has been declined by your `auto-load safe-path' set to "$debugdir:$datadir/auto-load".
To enable execution of this file add
        add-auto-load-safe-path /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db-1.0.so
line to your configuration file "/root/.gdbinit".
To completely disable this security protection add
        set auto-load safe-path /
line to your configuration file "/root/.gdbinit".
For more information about this security protection see the
"Auto-loading safe path" section in the GDB manual.  E.g., run from the shell:
        info "(gdb)Auto-loading safe path"

warning: Unable to find libthread_db matching inferior's thread library, thread debugging will not be available.

warning: File "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db-1.0.so" auto-loading has been declined by your `auto-load safe-path' set to "$debugdir:$datadir/auto-load".

warning: Unable to find libthread_db matching inferior's thread library, thread debugging will not be available.
Core was generated by `deploy/bin/amazing_app'.
Program terminated with signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
#0  0x00007f40abb1cfb7 in raise () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
[Current thread is 1 (LWP 22385)]
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007f40abb1cfb7 in raise () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007f40abb1e921 in abort () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#2  0x000055b6c3ca5595 in __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() ()
#3  0x000055b6c3c0d106 in __cxxabiv1::__terminate(void (*)()) ()
#4  0x000055b6c3c0d151 in std::terminate() ()
#5  0x000055b6c3c0b294 in __cxa_throw ()
#6  0x000055b6c2c64b55 in boost::throw_exception<boost::system::system_error> (e=...) at /root/amazing_app/include/boost/throw_exception.hpp:69
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
root@amazing_host:/coredump
```

Comment: It'd be interesting to see if you get some meaningful information out of running gdb on the gdb core file. Does the `system_error`  really say `e=...` or did you cut that part out?

Comment: Note that your amazing_app crashed with SIGABRT, not SIGSEGV.

Comment: @TedLyngmo it really says `e=...` exactly

Comment: @ks1322 That's true